# Set a UIView tag to numeric 0 in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, uiview, interface-builder

I figured a useful use of tags was to use them to establish a tab order for fields on a form. So I set each text field to have a tag of 0...n and using modulus n and `[UIView viewWithTag:]` to select the next text field in the tab order (wrapping around when it hits the end). However, the view with tag 0 is not being set to 0. Rather it is `nil` when I access it from code.

Why can't I set the view's tag to 0, even though it appears to be 0 in Interface Builder?

Is there any way around this? Having to use 1-indexed values would be very annoying as I can no longer use modulus to perform my wrap-around mathematics.

Comment: Can you share the code you are currently using to set the tag to 0?

Comment: I'm doing it in Interface Builder; having to set it in code would kind of defeat the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use your modulus math with 1 based values,

```
index = ((tag-1) %n) + 1;
```

where your tags are 1 to n,

Answer (score 2):

The default tag value is 0. So it's probably a case of you not getting back what you think you are getting as many views will have that value set.

A far better idea is to use a dictionary for your ordering.